# What happens when you encounter 2 same lowest values when creating Huffman tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, huffman-code

Lets say I have this probability table:
A -> 4,  B -> 2, C -> 2, D -> 1,  E->1

First I must combine D and E -> 2, but what must I combine next: DE+B/DE+C/B+C

```
_2_
|  |
D  E
1  1
```

So this above was the first step, but which of the next choices is correct and why?

```
1.)

 __4__
 |    |
_2_   |
|  |  |
D  E  B
1  1  2

2.)

 __4__
 |    |
_2_   |
|  |  |
D  E  C
1  1  2

3.)

 ____6____
 |       |
_4_     _2_
|  |    |  |
B  C    D  E
```

Answer (score 2):

> When you come to a fork in the road, take it.
> — Yogi Berra

*All* are correct. You can make any of those three choices, and all will result in an optimal Huffman code. Go ahead and complete the codes for all three. Then calculate how many bits will be used by each to code those symbols with those frequencies. You will see that they will all take exactly the same number of bits (22). Two will obviously be the same, but the third will be a different set of bit counts that sum to the same value.